# use Ajax for page linking in Express js and JQuery mobile

Tags: node.js, jquery-mobile, express

I'm using jquery mobile in my express project. How could I use Ajax for page linking instead of loading all the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the jquery get method to get the html content which you generate using express.

```
$.get( 'path/to/content', function( data ) {
  $( '#div' ).html( data );
});
```

In express you have something like:

```
app.get( '/path/to/content' , function( req , res ) {
    res.render( '<div>Some Content</div>' );
} );
```

In res.render you would usually render from a template rather than an HTML string.

Comment: Does express app.get() use ajax?

Comment: Ajax is just the browser requesting information from the server without a page refresh. The server doesn't know or care if it's Ajax or not. The Ajax part is the $.get();